# Numeric Functional Regression coefficients

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, regression-coefficients, functional-data-analysis

I'm working on some data where I have thousands of curves in the defined as:   $P(t)$ that basically represent eluition profiles of some proteins.

My aim is to represent each of this $P(t)$ curves as a linear combination of some other curves plus some error. More specifically:

$P(t) = \beta_{1} M(t) + \beta_2L(t)+\beta_3Z(t)+\beta_4G(t)+\epsilon$

Basically I want to find the scalar coefficient $\beta_1,\beta_2,..,\beta_n$ that minimize the residual sum of squares on $P(t)$ for me it seems like a simple multiple regression problem. The only issue seems to be that we are talking about functional data.

It seems that maybe can be a very simple problem, but I don't really know if I can just use simple linear regression to estimate the coefficients. I've heard about functional linear regression that takes the forms:

$P(t) = \beta_0(t)+\beta_1(t)M(t)+\beta_2(t)L(t)+\epsilon$

But in this case the coefficients are defined as functions, I really need them to be expressed as a scalar. Maybe I'm just a little bit confused, but It seems a very simple problem, there is a feasible way to resolve it?

Comment: Do you have a preferred programming language?

Comment: Yes, I use mainly R. It really seems a simple problem, but I'm not sure if I can resolve it with the classical `lm()` function. Unfortunately I think no.

Comment: Any hints or suggestions? :)

Comment: For y = f(x): if I have three vectors where the first vector is all 1.0, the second contains the values of x, and the third contains the values of x^2, when I perform linear regression  with linear algebra of y against these vectors I will have the coefficients a, b, c for the equation "y = a + b*x + c*x^2". Might you do something similar in this case, where you create vectors of the function values and then use standard linear algebra?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both models you mention fit into the framework of the varying coefficient models described originally by [Hastie and Tibshirani (1993)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2345993?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents).

From a functional data perspective, the second model you reference is called a functional current regression model. The first model is just a special case of the concurrent model where the coefficient functions are constant. For references, see [chapter 14 of Ramsay and Silverman's book (2005)](https://books.google.com/books?id=mU3dop5wY_4C&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false) or, more recently, [Leroux et. al. (2018)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/29230836). As with most functional data methods, whether your functional data are sparse or dense affects how you should conduct your analysis; the latter reference details a model-fitting procedure for when the functional data are sparsely sampled.

If you would like to fit such a model using R, the [fcr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fcr/index.html) package was designed to accompany the paper by Leroux et. al. (2018), but the pffr function of the [refund package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/refund/refund.pdf) can also be used to accomplish your goal.